# Storage file to System uri?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, storagefile

I have a Windows Metro app written in c#.

Here is the code I am using to pick a file from a local music library:

```
FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.MusicLibrary;
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wav");

StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
if (file != null)
{
   myMediaElement.Source = file; //error here
}
else
{
    //error here
}
```

It says that `StorageFile` cannot be converted to the `System.Uri` used to change the source of MediaElement. How do I make my file became a uri link? It seems that `Uri("...")` only accepts `String` of where the file location is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use a file stream along with `SetSource`. From [How to play a local media file using a MediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh871377.aspx):

```
var file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
myMediaElement.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
```